# how to scroll RecyclerView in scrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, scrollview

[image]

how to scroll all above RecyclerView in scrollview

I have to implement RecyclerView in scrollview show as below code, but not scroll RecyclerView.

please give answer

```
            <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

          <RelativeLayout...

                        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/rvpouch"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3">


                        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                    </RelativeLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Nesting scrollable Views is never a good idea.

Comment: try to use  "ScrollView" inside that use "LinearLayout" and inside put all your  "RecyclerView" .........may be its work

Answer (score 15):

Don't use `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView`. Use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView`.

> `NestedScrollView` is just like `ScrollView`, but it supports acting
>   as both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old
>   versions of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

**For Example:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_three"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Use attribute `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` for smooth scrolling.

Comment: above code not work.whole scrollview scroll if scroll

Comment: post you current layout xml.

Comment: it looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: but now above code resize as per data not show scrolling option i have to show scroll  option after some fix size

Comment: then use `fixed height` to your `RecyclerViews` using attribute `layout_height` or `layout_weight`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148190/discussion-between-adil-and-fat).

Comment: Glad to know that. If my answer seems useful then please mark as right answer and i hope you will give an up-vote too.

Answer (score 3):

Use NestedScrollView instead of scroll view and set

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: above code not work.whole scrollview scroll if scroll

Comment: what you exactly want, i think you want scroll multiple recyclerview and some  recyclerview horizontally

Answer (score -1):

Following code snippet will help you to implement scrolling using `ScrollView` of `RecyclerView`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarSize="3dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_black">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlFiltersSearchEvent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/action_bar_gradient">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvListOfEventsMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rlFiltersSearchEvent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Hope it helps**