# Two recycleviews in one activity scroll problem

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I have created 2 recycleviews in one activity. One scrolls horizontally while other scrolls vertically. I can scroll correctly inside each RecyclerView but the page as a whole won't scroll i.e. top RecyclerView stays at the top always and bottom one stays at the bottom like both are fixed in position.

```
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.shakeelnawaz.recipes.AllRecipesFragmet">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/trending_recipes"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontaltrendingrecycleview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:text="@string/all_recipes"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I read this post "[Scolling with multiple RecyclerViews in Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903390/scolling-with-multiple-recyclerviews-in-layout/30905075#30905075)"  and set vertical recycleview's height programmatically. like this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new     
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
// calculate height of RecyclerView based on child count
params.height=1150;
// set height of RecyclerView
recyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But the problem is that how I can calculate the height of RecyclerView based on child count?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to scroll RecyclerView in scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878863/how-to-scroll-recyclerview-in-scrollview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` 
and use this below line in your `Fragment` in `Activity`.

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(mYourRecycleView, false);
```

This will be work on all your Android API level.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollView`

Then add: `horizontaltrendingrecycleview.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false`

Your XML should look like below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true"
  tools:context="com.shakeelnawaz.recipes.AllRecipesFragmet">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      android:text="@string/trending_recipes"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/horizontaltrendingrecycleview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="240dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
      android:text="@string/all_recipes"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recycleView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

  </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```